# How to position the bubbles in bubble map statewise and in a row/column

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have used the following tutorial [Let's make a bubble map](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/bubble-map/) to create a state map with rectangle instead of circle to represent the constituencies of India. Instead of positioning the rectangle based on the constituency, I would like to position it one next to each other in a row/column above each of its state.

```
svg.selectAll(".state-stroke")
            .data(stateboundary).enter().append("path")
            .attr("d", geoPath)
            .attr("class", "state-stroke")
            .attr('stroke', "#888888")
            .attr('stroke-width', "0.8")
            .attr('fill', "none")
            .attr('stroke-opacity', "1")

svg.selectAll(".name").data(pcCentroid)
            .enter().append("rect")
            .attr("x", function(d){ return d[0]; })
            .attr("y", function (d){ return d[1]; })
            .attr("width", "3")
            .attr("height", "3")
            .attr("class", function(d,i){
                return stateboundary[i]['properties']['ST_CODE']
            });
```

I have included the full code here 
https://jsfiddle.net/diviseed/4qhnakwb/2/

It looks like the below map right now
[image]

The result I would like is something like below
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sheilak/ca3u4Lxh/) forked from your code.

First lets iterate over the constituencies and group them by state.

```
var constituenciesByState = {};
pathshape.objects.pcboundary.geometries
  .forEach(function(pc){
     var code = pc.properties.ST_CODE;
     if (!constituenciesByState[code]) {
        constituenciesByState[code] = [];
     }
     constituenciesByState[code].push(pc);
  });
```

Then modify the d3 code so instead of starting with `pcCentroid` data, we start with `stateCentroid` data, and append a new `svg` element for each state.

```
svg.selectAll(".name").data(stateCentroid)
  .enter().append("svg")
```

Then we generate the nested data for each constituency. First get the code for the current state, and get the array of relevant constituencies. Then we calculate the `rowLength`, you can change this logic based on your requirements. Then we calculate `initialX` and `initialY` to determine where the first point should go, based on the number of rows and columns. Then we use `map` to return a new object for each constituency, with `x`, `y`, `state` and `constituency` properties. The `x` and `y` values are modified to shift each item right and down according to their index.

```
.data(function(d, index) { 
  var stateCode = stateboundary[index]['properties']['ST_CODE'];
  var constituencies = constituenciesByState[stateCode];

  var rowLength = Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(constituencies.length));  // rectangles per row
  var offset = 5;  // spacing between start of each rectangle

  var numCols = Math.min(constituencies.length, rowLength);
  var numRows = Math.ceil(constituencies.length/rowLength);

  var initialX = d[0] - (numCols * offset)/2;
  var initialY = d[1] - (numRows * offset)/2;

  return constituencies
    .map(function(c, i) {
    return {
      x : initialX + ((i % rowLength) * offset),
      y : initialY + Math.floor(i / rowLength) * offset,
      constituency: c.properties.PC_CODE,
      state: stateCode
    }
  }); 
 })
```

Then slight modifications for the changes made to the format for each point, and to show constituency code in tooltip:

```
.attr("x", function(d){ return d.x })
.attr("y", function (d){ return d.y })
.attr("width", "3")
.attr("height", "3")
.attr("class", function(d,i){
    return d.state;
})
.append("title")
.text(function(d) { return d.constituency });
```

Comment: Thank you for the code.Just to clarify one more thing, how can I embed the constituency number apart from the state name for each rect. The Constituency number can be found in the PC boundary

Comment: in that case I would slightly change the approach - see edited answer (added Constituency number in tooltip to demonstrate)